# Iterate words as many for re.search python

Tags: python

I am trying to retrieve the paragraph contains the word from a website.The problem I do not know how many words are coming after the word so I need to iterate it.

```
import urllib.request
import re
url = "http://www.cnn.com"
request = urllib.request.Request(url)
html_content = urllib.request.urlopen(request)
mystring=html_content.read().decode('utf-8')
m = re.search('CNN\s\w+\s\w+\s\w+\s\w+\s\w+\s\w+\s\w+\s(\w+)',mystring)
print (m.group(0))
```

in this example I get news from CNN withthe keyword of Korea for example I want to get all paragraph till first period (.) or lets say punctutaion mark.

Comment: no idea what you are asking..

Comment: add more description to your question.

Comment: Try with an example...

Comment: add an example to your string.

Comment: I just edited edited all code ; I hope it explains my question.

Comment: Still unclear what you're asking... I think this needs to be put on hold

Comment: I dont know why I am still getting downvote ?? this is really disturbing :(

Comment: m = re.search('dummyword\s\w+\s\w+\s\w+\s\w+\s\w+\s\w+\s\w+\s(\w+)',mystring)

Comment: I had to write \s\w+ for everyword in sentence but I want to know if I can iterate this loop till first punctuation mark it can be dot or !

Comment: in other words is it possible to iterate regex or pattern to get as many words I can get till the end of sentence like . or !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if this really solves your problem. If you want your text be split into sentences use this:

`re.split(r'[\.\!]', text)`

If you want only the first sentence of a text use that:

`re.match(r'.*[\.\!]', text`

The dot means every character will be a match. Asterisk is the quantifier for zero or more occurances. The brackets contain the set of the last character, which is a dot or an exclamation mark.

if you want to find every sentence that contains a certain keyword use this:

`re.findall(r'[^\.\!]*KEYWORD[^\.\!]*[\.\!]', text)`

The circumflex at the beginning of the matching set of characters means every character *except* the given ones.

Comment: @sevn I just edited like this but still getting nonsense thing at the end of sentences.  `pattern=r'(Trump[^\.]*\,.)'   m = re.findall(pattern,mystring)`

Comment: after your answer I enhanced the code a little bit and add replace function for each char in my results to clean unnecesarry chars. I wish I could paste the code to here but it is not helping me to put end lines so code became useless :D